# Sharepoint list with calculated column - formula IF does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, error, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Working on a SharePoint list with a calculated column with a date, which I want to make dependent on priority (column is called `Prioriteit`), and date of creation (`Datum melding`).

I made this formula in Excel first (this worked):

```
=IF(B4="Hoog";A4+30;IF(B4="Midden";A4+60;IF(B4="Laag";A4+90)))
```

Then I tried  translating it for SharePoint:

```
=IF([Prioriteit]="Hoog";[Datum melding]+30;ALS([Prioriteit]="Midden";[Datum melding]+60;ALS([Prioriteit="Laag";[Datum melding]+90)))
```

It didn't work. The error I'm getting is"

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

I tried simpler equations with IF function like:

```
=IF([Prioriteit]="Hoog";[Datum melding]+30;10)
```

I tried replacing semicolons with commas, I tried replacing IF with ALS (conforming to my own language, tried deleting the `=` at the beginning.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to add days to date-time field? Also, try using this formula just to check if it works or not: `=IF([Prioriteit]="Hoog";true;false)`. If this does not work, try replacing `;` with `,`

Comment: Also, which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: @GaneshSanap: I tried your formula, doesn't work either. Replaced the semicolons and did all other things I mentioned above. I'm using SharePoint Online (Plan 2). 
I am trying to add days to a date field.

Comment: Strange. Make sure you are using the display name (name you see in form/list view) of your field `Prioriteit` and not the internal name of field.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it by adding another column and testing very slowly step by step. Working formula is this:

```
=IF(Prioriteit="Hoog",[Datum melding]+30,IF(Prioriteit="Midden",[Datum melding]+60,IF(Prioriteit="Laag",[Datum melding]+90)))
```

I think I just made a dumb little mistake with some symbol. Anyways, thanks @Ganesh for your help!